# What are the values after recentering?

Tags: meshlab

When I load a mesh and double click on a point, the text box in the lower left displays:

```
Recentering on point [-0.442816 0.900759 1.117096] [714,535]
```

What are these numbers? x, y, z and what and what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the 2D coordinates of the point where you clicked in the drawing area of MeshLab! Origin is in the bottom-left corner.

Comment: So nothing to do with the mesh.